# Jplayer not playing in Android Webview

Tags: android, mobile, webview, jplayer

I created an Android App which loads a webpage via Webview into the app so you can access the content on a mobile device. On the webpage, I have placed a radio player using iframe and it works. But when I try to click on it to play in the app, it doesn't work. The play button isn't responding at all. If you can point me in the right direction, I would be glad.

The webpage in question is [zeno.fm/repjesus-radio](https://www.zeno.fm/repjesus-radio), incase you would like to have a feel of the player.

Comment: Can you please show us your code of the webview creation and initialisation ?

Comment: @Bruno am not sure if I understand you. You want the full code posted here?